# How to change initial value in redux-form with react-native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I want to make an addition button and that the value initialize in 0 and make two buttons of addition and subtraction and a text that shows the value, until now I could change the value using the onChange but I could not set a default value to the value and it happens something weird that when pressing the button of addition it increases as if it were string, if someone knows how to make a functional button he would really appreciate it.
My code

```
    const renderCantPersonas = ({ input: { onChange, value }, text }) => {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <View style={{ flexDirection: "row", alignItems: "center" }}>
        <Text style={styles.textBtn}>{text}</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={{
            alignItems: "center"
          }}
          onPress={() => {
            onChange(value + 1);
          }}
        >
          <Icon
            name="add"
            size={20}
            style={styles.icon}
            color={DEFAULT_FONT_COLOR}
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <Text style={styles.textValue}>{value ? value : 0}</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => {
            value: 0, onChange(value - 1);
          }}
        >
          <Icon
            name="remove"
            size={20}
            style={styles.icon}
            color={DEFAULT_FONT_COLOR}
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

<Field
        name="CantPersonas2"
        component={renderCantPersonas}
        text="Cantidad de personas para la visita:"
      />

export default reduxForm({
  form: TITLE_FORM_VISITA,
  validate
})(Form);
```